# Are the basis vectors of a subspace also a subset of the basis vectors of the vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Would this be true for all cases? My homework problems are about T-invariant subspaces linear transformations, and I was asked to find a basis for the whole vector space. I was wondering if I could write the basis for the subspace as a subset of the vector space.

Comment: The question in the title is different from the last sentence (question) in the body. For $\mathbb R^2$ the examples you can find to answer both questions are quite simple. Any ideas ?

Comment: If you arbitrarily take a basis of the subspace and a basis of the whole vector space, it won't be the case. However, you can always expand a basis of subspace to a basis of the vector space. You can refer to Theorem 2.33 in Linear Algebra Done Right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we construct two bases for the same vector space with no vectors common to them.
Here is one way to construct such basis:
Let B be a basis for $R^n$. Let $M>0$ be a number greater than all the components of all the vectors in B.
Then the vectors M.v for all v in B also form a  new basis B' for $R^n$.
Easy to see that B and B' have no vectors in common.

Now a  basis for a subspace cannot be a subset of two disjoint subsets B and B'.

Now you can get the answer to your question from here.